# Why can't we have a truely WYSIWYG latex IDE?

Tags: markdown, mathjax, wysiwyg

There is Lyx where you can see what you get, but it's not latex. Hence not as compatible as it could be.

There's Markdown which can be converted into latex.
The good part about Markdown is, that you can live preview it with by converting it into HTML. Hence you can see what you get right beside your text file.
Then, there's a software called [Typora](https://typora.io/) which is truly WYSIWYG.
As soon as you end your line it gets displayed (rendered?) as a math equation (with [mathjax](https://www.mathjax.org/)

Another possibility would be to use a jupyter notebook where you can write each line as a cell, or each block or whatsoever.
After finishing a cell, you get a nice looking text.
But you can't easily convert it to tex and then to pdf.

So, I've experimented with a lot of languages, ides, etc.. Why can't we have a real WYSIWYG latex or markdown editor? Typora is very good, but it's only one developer, i.e. development could be faster or larger. Why can't we simply include [KaTeX](https://katex.org/) Mathjax, etc. into a strong ide like VScode, Atom, ...

Why can't we have it?

Edit: Attachment:
[image]

Comment: My question would be: why do you want it?

Comment: You'd finally beat word. AFAIK currently there's no software that can do that :/

Comment: Finely-grained typography requires finely-grained input. You cannot have the cake and eat it.

Comment: As soon as I write `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} ... \end{document}` everything important is known. the format, size, font etc.. PDF does not need to be the intermediate output, but the final one. Adding a line within the latex body does not change anything, maybe the number of pages. It changes distances, but nothing crutial.  HTML can do it, not as beautiful as tex but it renders text.

Comment: TeX, the idea of it and its implementation, is decades old. Back then, computing power was costly and expensive. You compiled, when you were sure you wouldn't waste any processing time.

Comment: I added a screenshot of Typora where I write my sections in. Just really beautiful. It's a Markdown flavor, but that's ok, I can convert it to tex as soon as the paper is finished. I'm glad I write latex and not tex! =)

Comment: I had to write my beamer template in tex and in css such that I can have a live preview of my final slides with xaringan or weave, with nearly the same settings, such that I can adjust my text in real time to the slide. I do not face the pain of beamer latex and can just use dashes within my plain text. all the beautiful formatting is done afterwards. But I have to use two completely different things...

Comment: One of the often cited advantages of LaTeX is the separation between content and formatting. You either concentrate on the content *or* formatting. You should never concentrate on both at the same time.

Comment: @Johannes_B I agree. But you can't see how many lines you have left on a slide because you just don't know how it'll be rendered. Hence, it is very helpful to see how much space you have used. You just don't need to take care about formatting once you've set it all up

Comment: @peter41992 there are lots of systems that run tex continuously showing the output so you can see your beamer slide in more or less real time in a system like overleaf

Comment: @DavidCarlisle not really, you still need to compile the script. With HTML I have it just in time.

Comment: rstudio and now texstudio has shown that you can preview equations right below the equation, just hide the equation and you have a little wysiwyg..

Comment: having two windows open with the same information is just a waste of space. But thx anyway.

Comment: For Powerpoint there is [IguanaTex](http://www.jonathanleroux.org/software/iguanatex/), which implements some of the ideas you mention (sort of). You click on an equation in your WYSIWYG view (i.e., when editing a slide in Powerpoint), then a small popup appears where you can edit the LaTeX code for that equation and see the changes on the slide (not fully automatic, you need to press a button to view the changes). IguanaTeX is real LaTeX, with packages etc. The rest of the document is still 'normal' Powerpoint though, so it's not a full LaTeX document editor.

Comment: @Marijn I won't ever go back to PP :D but thx! I didn't know that existed and I got to know [UOCS](https://www.ucsusa.org/) thx!

Comment: However, the only real difference between your description (i.e., the Typora example) and side-by-side views such as Overleaf or TeXstudio seems to be that the LaTeX code appears in between the document preview instead of to the left of it. But given the fact that you will have LaTeX source code visible most of the time when editing, the savings in space to show the same part of the document seem rather small, especially when you put the side-by-side windows vertically (code above or below the preview). And with SyncTeX (used by most previewers) the "click somewhere in the preview and go [...]

Comment: [...] to that position in the source" is rather accurate, so this is already very close to the setup that you are looking for, it seems.

Comment: For starters some of my documents take 15 minutes to compile. Some chapters take several minutes.

Comment: In your initial line you say that  lyx (which uses latex to produce the output) is discounted as it  "is not latex"  yet later you say that typora, which uses mathjax (which does not use tex at all)  is wysywig.  What do you mean by this comparison?